# onAdImpression() not getting Called in Admob Listener

Tags: java, android, admob

In Banner ad `onAdImpression()` not getting called any more.

```
 mAdview = findViewById(R.id.bannertest);
    mAdview.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdClosed() {
            super.onAdClosed();
            Log.w(TAG, "onAdClosed: ");
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdFailedToLoad(int i) {
            super.onAdFailedToLoad(i);
            Log.w(TAG, "onAdFailedToLoad: ");

        }

        @Override
        public void onAdLeftApplication() {
            super.onAdLeftApplication();
            Log.w(TAG, "onAdLeftApplication: ");
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdOpened() {
            super.onAdOpened();
            Log.w(TAG, "onAdOpened: ");
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdLoaded() {
            super.onAdLoaded();
            Log.w(TAG, "onAdLoaded: ");
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdClicked() {
            super.onAdClicked();
            Log.w(TAG, "onAdClicked: ");
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdImpression() {
            super.onAdImpression();
            Log.w(TAG, "onAdImpression: ");
        }
    });
    mAdview.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
```

is there any way to track the impression for banner ad?

Comment: do you have any updates related to this issue?

Comment: I am also facing the same issue.

Comment: i posted answer it may helps @user93796

Answer (score 6):

Ref: https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/mediation/MediationNativeListener#onAdImpression(com.google.android.gms.ads.mediation.MediationNativeAdapter)

```
public abstract void onAdImpression (MediationNativeAdapter adapter)
```

Indicates that an impression has been recorded for the ad. This method should only `be called if` `setOverrideImpressionRecording(boolean) is set to true`. This is used for publisher metrics, and must be called in addition to any other events.

Read More https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/mediation/MediationNativeListener#onAdImpression(com.google.android.gms.ads.mediation.MediationNativeAdapter)

**Edit 2**

https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/mediation/NativeAdMapper

**Edit 3**

> An impression simply says that the ad is present so the onAdLoaded is
>   where you would want to place your impression tracking.

Comment: I am still confused. I was assuming that this method is called by SDK if it counts the impression as a valid impression. Is my understanding correct?And to enable this listener i have to call 'setOverrideImpressionRecording(boolean)'

Comment: I cant find that setOverrideImpressionRecording(boolean) method in AdView class.

Comment: The link u provided is for mediation. I want to count impressions of AdView. How do i link NativeAdMapper to AdView?

Answer (score 0):

I found this method confusing as well, but according to the documentation, it is called only for some native ads.

```
public void onAdImpression ()
```

> Called when an impression is recorded for an ad. At the current time,
>   this method is only used with native ads originating from Google in
>   one of the system-defined formats (App Install or Content).

https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/AdListener#public-void-onadimpression